# XPath to select preceding input

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, siblings

```
<tr class="dark">
    <td width="10%" valign="top">
        <input id="b5c7704b641c4e290164831754a200d1" name="rowCheckBox" value="BCM$b5c7704b641c4e290164831754a200d1$$$ACCEPTED$Released$false" type="radio" valign="top" onclick="javascript:handlebuttons()" />
    </td>
    <td style="word-wrap : break-word ;overflow:hidden;" title="AttachmentService" width="30%" valign="top">
        <img src="images/service_released.PNG" onmouseover="javascript:showToolTip('Released',this)" onmouseout="hideToolTip()" style="padding-right:5px;" width="18px" height="18px" border="0" align="top" />AttachmentService</td>
    <td style="word-wrap : break-word ;overflow:hidden;" width="15%" valign="top">SOAP</td>
    <td style="word-wrap : break-word ;overflow:hidden;" width="15%" valign="top">Sync</td>
    <td style="word-wrap : break-word ;overflow:hidden;" width="15%" valign="top">1.17</td>
    <td width="15%" valign="top">Released</td>
    <td style="word-wrap : break-word ;overflow:hidden;" width="15%" valign="top">ACCEPTED</td>
</tr>
```

I am using selenium, and I want it to click on the radio button that is right before the `'AttachmentService'` for version `'1.17'`

I have tried the following:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//td[contains(@title, AttachmentService')]//preceding::input[1]"))
```

but I want to include `1.17` because we have many `AttachmentService` with different versions like **1.15, 1.16, 1.17**

How to handle this?

Answer (score 2):

use `following-sibling`

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//td[following-sibling::td[@title='AttachmentService'] and following-sibling::td[text()='1.17']]/input"));
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use `following-sibling` to add `<td>` with a specific version and use `preceding` from that element

```
String version = "1.17";
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//td[contains(@title, 'AttachmentService')]/following-sibling::td[.='" + version + "']//preceding::input[1]"));
```